# Matrix norm applications?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

There'are many different ways to calculate  [Matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

But once calculated, what is the practical use/application of it (e.g. in computer programming)?

Or does it let define something that can be used in practice? What?

Comment: You might want to look at:  http://www.emis.de/journals/GMN/yahoo_site_admin/assets/docs/Chen_paper-5.6683552.pdf, http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01942607, http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3987,

Comment: One application of a matrix norm is that it gives up a metric space.  In other words, we can use it to measure the "distance" between two matrices via $d(A, B) = || A - B ||$.